# Read files using CAT or AWK for better execution time

Tags: bash, time, awk, benchmarking, cat

I have two same scripts . In one I'm using cat and in other it's all AWK.

Here's the first one:

```
#!/bin/bash


        lines=$(cat /etc/passwd | wc -l)

        for ((i=1 ; i <=$lines ; i++ ))
        do
        user=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $1}')
        uid=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $3}')
        gid=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $4}')
        shell=$(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $7}')
        echo -e "User is : $user \t Uid is : $uid \t Gid is : $gid \t Shell is : $shell"
        done
```

Here's the second one:

```
#!/bin/bash


        lines=$(awk  'END {print NR}' /etc/passwd)

        for ((i=1 ; i <=$lines ; i++ ))
        do
        user=$(awk  -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $1}' /etc/passwd)
        uid=$(awk  -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $3}'  /etc/passwd)
        gid=$(awk  -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $4}'  /etc/passwd)
        shell=$(awk  -F : -vi=$i 'NR==i {print $7}' /etc/passwd)
        echo -e "User is : $user \t Uid is : $uid \t Gid is : $gid \t Shell is : $shell"
        done
```

The time taken for the first script is as follows ( script with CAT statements):

```
real    0m0.215s
user    0m0.023s
sys     0m0.238s
```

For the second script which has only AWK statements, time taken is as follows:

```
real    0m0.132s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.123s
```

I think awk processing of file is much faster as compared to calling other external function for reading the files. I would be happy for a discussion on the results.

I think AWK performs better in some cases.

This is regarding this question here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/564944/cat-vs-grep-vs-awk-command-get-the-file-content-which-one-is-more-efficient-and/801569#801569

Comment: Are you aware of this:  http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html ?

Answer (score 8):

Clearly this:

```
lines=$(cat /etc/passwd | wc -l)
```

Is less efficient than this:

```
lines=$(awk  'END {print NR}' /etc/passwd)
```

For a file of this size, the cost of executing each process is significant compared to the processing time.

Neither approach is great, though. If you want to get the length of a file, just use `wc -l < file`.

Anyway, your loop would be much faster written as a single awk program like this:

```
awk -F: '{ 
  printf "User is : %s \t Uid is : %s \t Gid is : %s \t Shell is : %s\n", 
    $1, $3, $4, $7 
}' /etc/passwd
```

You could achieve even better performance by using `print` instead of `printf`.

```
awk -F: '{ 
  print "User is : " $1 " \t Uid is : " $3 " \t Gid is : " $4 " \t Shell is : " $7
}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Hi Tom,
I agree that the following would be more better

'awk -F: '{ 
  printf "User is : %s \t Uid is : %s \t Gid is : %s \t Shell is : %s\n", 
    $1, $3, $4, $7 
}' /etc/passwd'

I was asking in general whether using builtin capability of a function is much better as compared to other thing. For example in a for loop in bash we have different ways:

`for (( i=1; i<j; i++ )) ...kinf of syntax'

we can also use

` #!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 5)
do
  echo "Welcome $i times"
done
`

Here we are using seq for the increment  which is an external command.

Comment: @Himanshu it's hard to generalise about this kind of thing but then again, the difference in performance between each of those approaches is likely to be negligible compared to the cost of calling external programs within the loop. Furthermore, using a single tool designed to process entire files (such as awk), will in most cases be faster than using shell loops.

Comment: Thanks tom for your reply.